# Add member to telegram channel

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, add-member

I have been looking for a way to add a number of users to a telegram channel (with users id) for a long time and I didn't find anything. (I'm sure there is such a thing because I know people who do it but IDK and they don't tell me how it is done).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note that only the first 200 members can be added to a Telegram channel, and you should be aware that you are subject to get limited or banned if you abuse the Telegram API.

You can add members to a Telegram channel by calling the [`channels.inviteToChannel`](https://github.com/telegramdesktop/tdesktop/blob/015c5d961878358060449d190442797e5aeb62c6/Telegram/Resources/tl/api.tl#L1679) method.

If you use Python, you can do that easily with [Pyrogram](https://pyrogram.org):

```py
client.add_chat_members(
  channel_id,
  [user_ids],
)
```

You can also call the method easily with [GramJS](https://github.com/gram-js/gramjs), if using JavaScript:

```js
client.invoke(
  new Api.channels.InviteToChannel({
    channel: channelId,
    users: [userIds],
  })
)
```

Comment: Is there any way to add a bot to a channel? 
I use `GramJS` to create a channel programatically. Then, I wanna add a bot to the newly created channel. For this, I use `InviteToChannel` method, but it doesn't work. It crashes with the error `RPCError: 400: USER_BOT (caused by channels.InviteToChannel)`.
Any ideas, folks?